# Does return is added implicitly in a callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a code (attached screenshot) that in one place it is written explictiy **reutrn** inside a callback, and in another one it isn't. I'm trying to understand what is the reason for it? In my opinion return statement should be added also in the first one. Am i wrong?

[image]

Comment: in the block {}, you need a return keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a return in the first one. Read this about arrow functions

"(...) If the function has only one statement, and the statement returns a value, you can remove the brackets and the return keyword" - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is a property of the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions): if the braces are omitted the result of the following statement is returned automatically.

`input => output` is the same as `input => { return output; }`.

Note that this behavior differs from regular functions, as these two functions do not both return a result:

```
function a(input) { return 1 };
function b(input) { 1 };
a() // 1
b() // undefined
```

Comment: Hello @soimon Hope you are doing good !!! How is life Mate :)

Comment: @soimon, thanks for the answer. i voted it up, but J.Langer was to first to answer (also a good answer), therefore i have approved his answer. thanks!!!